# xunit.core is incompatible with version of NuGet

Tags: tfs, msbuild, xunit, build-server

I added a new project to the solution. I've added some nuget packages however it fails when building on TFS. It works fine when building locally. I get the following error messages:

```
 C:\Builds\8\Server-Dev-CI\src\.nuget\NuGet.targets (58): The schema version of 'xunit.core' is incompatible with version 2.0.30828.5 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
 C:\Builds\8\Server-Dev-CI\src\.nuget\NuGet.targets (58): The schema version of 'xunit.extensibility.execution' is incompatible with version 2.0.30828.5 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.
 C:\Builds\8\Server-Dev-CI\src\.nuget\NuGet.targets (58): One or more errors occurred.
 C:\Builds\8\Server-Dev-CI\src\.nuget\NuGet.targets (58): The command ""C:\Builds\8\Server-Dev-CI\src\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\Builds\8\Server-Dev-CI\src\Modules\UnitTests.xUnit\packages.config" -source "https://nuget.org/api/v2/" -o "C:\Builds\8\Server-Dev-CI\src\packages"" exited with code 1.
```

When I open the sources in VS2013 (on the build server) I see the following:
[image]

I have to click Restore Packages to get it to work. 
[image]

I already updated NuGet. Where is it getting " 2.0.30828.5 of NuGet" from???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The whole time I though TFS uses Visual Studio's NuGet, however it turns out TFS runs:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\nuget.exe restore
```

I had to open up console and update nuget:

```
nuget.exe update -self
```